# How to focus on required or invalid field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, checkvalidity

I have form that is long and in some situations users might miss some of the required fields. If they scroll all the way to the `Save` button and click to send the form data they won't see error message. I'm wondering if there is a way to trigger `on focus` method that will take user to the first field in the form that is `required` or `invalid`. Here is example of my form:

```js
var COMMON_FUNC = {};
$("#save").on("click", function() {
  var frmObject = $(this).closest("form"),
    frmDisabledFlds = frmObject.find(":input:disabled").prop("disabled", false),
    frmData = frmObject.serialize();
  frmDisabledFlds.prop("disabled", true);

  if (COMMON_FUNC.verifyFields("new-record")) {
    console.log('Send Form Data!');
  }
});

COMMON_FUNC.verifyFields = function(containerID, includeInvisible) {
  includeInvisible = includeInvisible || false;
  let isValid = true;
  const hdlMap = {
    'valueMissing': "This field is required",
    'patternMismatch': "This field is invalid",
    'tooLong': "This field is too long",
    'rangeOverflow': "This field is greater than allowed maximum",
    'rangeUnderflow': "This field is less than allowed minimum",
    'typeMismatch': "This field is mistyped"
  };

  const arrV = Object.keys(hdlMap);

  $("#" + containerID).find("input,textarea,select").each(function() {
    var curItem$ = $(this);
    var errMsg = [];
    var dispfld = curItem$.data("dispfld");

    if (includeInvisible || curItem$.is(":visible")) {
      if (curItem$[0].validity.valid) {
        curItem$.removeClass("is-invalid");
        return;
      }

      arrV.forEach(function(prop) {
        if (curItem$[0].validity[prop]) {
          if (prop === "patternMismatch" && dispfld) {
            errMsg.push(dispfld);
          } else {
            errMsg.push(hdlMap[prop]);
          }
        }
      });

      if (errMsg.length) {
        if (!curItem$.next().is(".invalid-feedback")) {
          curItem$.after('<div class="invalid-feedback"></div>');
        }
        curItem$.addClass("is-invalid").next().text(errMsg.join(' and '));
        isValid = false;
      } else {
        curItem$.removeClass("is-invalid");
      }
    }
  });

  return isValid;
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h4>New Record</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <form name="new-record" id="new-record" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="bldg_name">Building Name:</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="bldg_name" id="bldg_name" value="" maxlength="500" placeholder="Enter the building name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12"><strong><u>Manager</u></strong></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-6">
            <label for="salutation">Salutation:</label>
            <select class="custom-select browser-default" name="salutation" id="salutation">
              <option value="">--Select Salutation--</option>
              <option value="1">Mrs</option>
              <option value="2">Ms</option>
              <option value="3">Miss</option>
              <option value="4">Mr</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-6">
            <label for="title">Business Title:</label>
            <select class="custom-select browser-default" name="title" id="title">
              <option value="">--Select Title--</option>
              <option value="1">Region Manager</option>
              <option value="2">State Manager</option>
              <option value="3">Building Manager</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-6 required">
            <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" maxlength="20" placeholder="Enter First name" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-6 required">
            <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter Last name" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input class="form-control email" type="email" name="email" id="email" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter Email address" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-5 offset-2"><strong><u>Physical Address</u></strong></div>
          <div class="col-5"><strong><u>Mailing Address</u></strong></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row required">
          <label for="address1" class="col-2 col-form-label">Address 1:</label>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control physical" type="text" name="p_address1" id="p_address1" value="" placeholder="Enter Physical Address 1" maxlength="40" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control mailing" type="text" name="m_address1" id="m_address1" value="" placeholder="Enter Mailing Address 1" maxlength="40" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="address2" class="col-2 col-form-label">Address 2:</label>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control physical" type="text" name="p_address2" id="p_address2" value="" placeholder="Enter Physical Address 2" maxlength="40">
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control mailing" type="text" name="m_address2" id="m_address2" value="" placeholder="Enter Mailing Address 2" maxlength="40">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="address3" class="col-2 col-form-label">Address 3:</label>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control physical" type="text" name="p_address3" id="p_address3" value="" placeholder="Enter Physical Address 3" maxlength="40">
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control mailing" type="text" name="m_address3" id="m_address3" value="" placeholder="Enter Mailing Address 3" maxlength="40">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="address4" class="col-2 col-form-label">Address 4:</label>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control physical" type="text" name="p_address4" id="p_address4" value="" placeholder="Enter Physical Address 4" maxlength="40">
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control mailing" type="text" name="m_address4" id="m_address4" value="" placeholder="Enter Mailing Address 4" maxlength="40">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row required">
          <label for="city" class="col-2 col-form-label">City:</label>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control physical" type="text" name="p_city" id="p_city" value="" placeholder="Enter City" maxlength="25" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control mailing" type="text" name="m_city" id="m_city" value="" placeholder="Enter City" maxlength="25" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row required">
          <label for="state" class="col-2 col-form-label">State:</label>
          <div class="col-5">
            <select class="custom-select browser-default physical" name="p_state" id="p_state" required>
              <option value="">--Select State--</option>
              <option value="az">Arizona</option>
              <option value="ia">Iowa</option>
              <option value="mo">Missouri</option>
              <option value="ny">New York</option>
              <option value="va">Virginia</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <select class="custom-select browser-default mailing" name="m_state" id="m_state" required>
              <option value="">--Select State--</option>
              <option value="az">Arizona</option>
              <option value="ia">Iowa</option>
              <option value="mo">Missouri</option>
              <option value="ny">New York</option>
              <option value="va">Virginia</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row required">
          <label for="zip" class="col-2 col-form-label">Zip:</label>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control physical" type="text" name="p_zip" id="p_zip" value="" pattern="(\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?)" data-dispfld="The required format is: xxxxx or xxxxx-xxxx" placeholder="Enter Zip Code, formatted: 99999 or 99999-9999" maxlength="10" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control mailing" type="text" name="m_zip" id="m_zip" value="" pattern="(\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?)" data-dispfld="The required format is: xxxxx or xxxxx-xxxx" placeholder="Enter Zip Code, formatted: 99999 or 99999-9999" maxlength="10" required>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" name="save" id="save">Save</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" name="cancel" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can run this example and enter all information in the form but Building Name. Then you can click Save button, and you won;t be able to see the error message on the top. If anyone have suggestions how to handle this problem please let me know. I open to hear different solutions for this situations.

Comment: maybe you could [`scroll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll) to the first input with error

Comment: @jonatjano Can you please provide an example? Thank you.

Comment: I can't now and I don't know if I'll get time to do it today, I'll do it tomorrow if nobody's done it until then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM API has a "focus" function on elements that can do what you're looking for.

Push all your valid elements to an invalidInputs array, then you can choose the first element that is invalid and call .focus() on that element.

```js
var COMMON_FUNC = {};
$("#save").on("click", function() {
  var frmObject = $(this).closest("form"),
    frmDisabledFlds = frmObject.find(":input:disabled").prop("disabled", false),
    frmData = frmObject.serialize();
  frmDisabledFlds.prop("disabled", true);

  if (COMMON_FUNC.verifyFields("new-record")) {
    console.log('Send Form Data!');
  }
});

COMMON_FUNC.verifyFields = function(containerID, includeInvisible) {
  includeInvisible = includeInvisible || false;
  let isValid = true;
  const hdlMap = {
    'valueMissing': "This field is required",
    'patternMismatch': "This field is invalid",
    'tooLong': "This field is too long",
    'rangeOverflow': "This field is greater than allowed maximum",
    'rangeUnderflow': "This field is less than allowed minimum",
    'typeMismatch': "This field is mistyped"
  };

  const arrV = Object.keys(hdlMap);

  // Create an array for the invalid fields.
  const invalidInputs = [];

  $("#" + containerID).find("input,textarea,select").each(function() {
    var curItem$ = $(this);
    var errMsg = [];
    var dispfld = curItem$.data("dispfld");

    if (includeInvisible || curItem$.is(":visible")) {
      if (curItem$[0].validity.valid) {
        curItem$.removeClass("is-invalid");
        return;
      }

      arrV.forEach(function(prop) {
        if (curItem$[0].validity[prop]) {
          if (prop === "patternMismatch" && dispfld) {
            errMsg.push(dispfld);
          } else {
            errMsg.push(hdlMap[prop]);
          }
        }
      });

      if (errMsg.length) {
        if (!curItem$.next().is(".invalid-feedback")) {
          curItem$.after('<div class="invalid-feedback"></div>');
        }
        curItem$.addClass("is-invalid").next().text(errMsg.join(' and '));
        isValid = false;
        
        //Push the invalid inputs onto the invalidInputs array.
        invalidInputs.push(curItem$);
      } else {
        curItem$.removeClass("is-invalid");
      }
    }
  });
 
  // Focus on the first element that is invalid.
  invalidInputs[0].focus();

  return isValid;
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h4>New Record</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <form name="new-record" id="new-record" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="bldg_name">Building Name:</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="bldg_name" id="bldg_name" value="" maxlength="500" placeholder="Enter the building name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12"><strong><u>Manager</u></strong></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-6">
            <label for="salutation">Salutation:</label>
            <select class="custom-select browser-default" name="salutation" id="salutation">
              <option value="">--Select Salutation--</option>
              <option value="1">Mrs</option>
              <option value="2">Ms</option>
              <option value="3">Miss</option>
              <option value="4">Mr</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-6">
            <label for="title">Business Title:</label>
            <select class="custom-select browser-default" name="title" id="title">
              <option value="">--Select Title--</option>
              <option value="1">Region Manager</option>
              <option value="2">State Manager</option>
              <option value="3">Building Manager</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-6 required">
            <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" maxlength="20" placeholder="Enter First name" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-6 required">
            <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter Last name" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input class="form-control email" type="email" name="email" id="email" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter Email address" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-5 offset-2"><strong><u>Physical Address</u></strong></div>
          <div class="col-5"><strong><u>Mailing Address</u></strong></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row required">
          <label for="address1" class="col-2 col-form-label">Address 1:</label>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control physical" type="text" name="p_address1" id="p_address1" value="" placeholder="Enter Physical Address 1" maxlength="40" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control mailing" type="text" name="m_address1" id="m_address1" value="" placeholder="Enter Mailing Address 1" maxlength="40" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="address2" class="col-2 col-form-label">Address 2:</label>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control physical" type="text" name="p_address2" id="p_address2" value="" placeholder="Enter Physical Address 2" maxlength="40">
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control mailing" type="text" name="m_address2" id="m_address2" value="" placeholder="Enter Mailing Address 2" maxlength="40">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="address3" class="col-2 col-form-label">Address 3:</label>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control physical" type="text" name="p_address3" id="p_address3" value="" placeholder="Enter Physical Address 3" maxlength="40">
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control mailing" type="text" name="m_address3" id="m_address3" value="" placeholder="Enter Mailing Address 3" maxlength="40">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="address4" class="col-2 col-form-label">Address 4:</label>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control physical" type="text" name="p_address4" id="p_address4" value="" placeholder="Enter Physical Address 4" maxlength="40">
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control mailing" type="text" name="m_address4" id="m_address4" value="" placeholder="Enter Mailing Address 4" maxlength="40">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row required">
          <label for="city" class="col-2 col-form-label">City:</label>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control physical" type="text" name="p_city" id="p_city" value="" placeholder="Enter City" maxlength="25" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control mailing" type="text" name="m_city" id="m_city" value="" placeholder="Enter City" maxlength="25" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row required">
          <label for="state" class="col-2 col-form-label">State:</label>
          <div class="col-5">
            <select class="custom-select browser-default physical" name="p_state" id="p_state" required>
              <option value="">--Select State--</option>
              <option value="az">Arizona</option>
              <option value="ia">Iowa</option>
              <option value="mo">Missouri</option>
              <option value="ny">New York</option>
              <option value="va">Virginia</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <select class="custom-select browser-default mailing" name="m_state" id="m_state" required>
              <option value="">--Select State--</option>
              <option value="az">Arizona</option>
              <option value="ia">Iowa</option>
              <option value="mo">Missouri</option>
              <option value="ny">New York</option>
              <option value="va">Virginia</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row required">
          <label for="zip" class="col-2 col-form-label">Zip:</label>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control physical" type="text" name="p_zip" id="p_zip" value="" pattern="(\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?)" data-dispfld="The required format is: xxxxx or xxxxx-xxxx" placeholder="Enter Zip Code, formatted: 99999 or 99999-9999" maxlength="10" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control mailing" type="text" name="m_zip" id="m_zip" value="" pattern="(\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?)" data-dispfld="The required format is: xxxxx or xxxxx-xxxx" placeholder="Enter Zip Code, formatted: 99999 or 99999-9999" maxlength="10" required>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" name="save" id="save">Save</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" name="cancel" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, but a small correction on terminology... `.focus()` is a DOM method - - it's not part of JavaScript, it's part of the DOM API.

Comment: This solution seems to work pretty well. Is there a way to add smooth scroll/focus instead of jumping so fat? Thank you.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for that correction, I've edited that in. 

espresso, a combination of smooth-scrolling followed by the call to "focus" should do the trick. I'll leave that up to you, but here's a start: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section2

Answer (score 1):

You can try something simple like this (untested but should work):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('is-invalid')[0].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
```

This looks for error class `is-invalid` then does a smooth scroll to the first one found

Add this code after the validation, if there are errors found.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to provide example for this questions.

Answer (score 0):

On the button you need to bind the event using a function like the below one:

```
function submitForm(event) {
 for (var i = 0; i < event.elements.length; i++) {
                if (event.elements[i].required) {
                    if (event.elements[i].value == "") {
                        event.elements[i].focus();
                        break;
                    }
                }
          }
}
```

I hope this could help ~Rdaksh